# Rails: form multiple select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I try to assign some people to one task. Therefore I need to choose some people to name for a task. Therefore, I need to select multiple people's name. However, I do not know how to do multiple selections after searching for some information on StackOverflow. I do not know which parameters should be put into.

I have tried to do something on task/new.html.erb.This is what I have tried below.but, it shows the undefined method TYPE. Please tell me what should I do to achieve multiple seletion

```
The task/new.html.erb
<div class="card">
  <h5 class="card-header">Create Task</h5>
  <div class="card-body">
    <%= form_for @task, url:task_index_path(),method: :post do |f| %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :Task_ID %>
        <%= f.text_area :task_number,class: 'form-control'%>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :Description %>
        <%= f.text_field :desp,class:'form-control'%>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :Choose_People %>
        <%= f.select(:TYPE,User.all.collect{|p|[p.name, p.id]},{:prompt => "Please select"},{ :multiple => true,:size=>5})%>
      </div>

      <%=f.submit "Create",class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

This is task.rb
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_tasks
  has_many :users, through: :user_tasks
  enum status:{'unfinished':0,'done':1,'overtime':2}
end
It is my user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_tasks
  has_many :tasks, through: :user_tasks
end
it is my user_task.rb
class UserTask < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :task
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: Do you have column `type` in `task` model?
It seems you dont have any column like `type` in `task` model, if you are using `f.select` then you have to use form columns only, If you want to use column not from form object, then you can use `select_tag`

Comment: I do not have  type in task model. If it is select_tag what should I write? THx

Comment: In which table you want to store select boc values?

Comment: i want to get user.name

Comment: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag

Comment: @HaoWen Can you show schema for `User `model?

Comment: I have updated more details  @Gabbar

Comment: @HaoWen That's not what i mean. anyway can you write all columns or attributes names in user mode.?

Comment: @Gabbar I have fixed problem. It should be  <%= f.select(:user_ids,User.all.collect{|p|[p.name, p.id]},{:prompt => "Please select"},{ :multiple => true,:size=>6})%>

Comment: @HaoWen Glad to know that.

Comment: Side note: You should rename that column.... :type is a reserved column name in Rails.